# Circular importing error using wagtail-generic-chooser

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, importerror, wagtail

I am using wagtails wagtail-generic-chooser to create customChoosers for my data models and it is working great whenever I am referencing other modelAdmin models.

However, I have come across a situation where I have a Lexis model with a field that has a FK link to itself. The idea is to have a Lexis term, and then there can be related lexis terms connected to it. It works fine with a normal FieldPanel but this isn't a very good UI experience when there are hundreds of lexis terms. Accordingly, I wanted to create a custom LexisChooser for this field. However, the issue I've run into is according to the documentation in order to create a functional widget, I am required to create both a view and adminChooser that references the model the ChooserPanel is connected to.

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-generic-chooser#chooser-widgets-model-based

This makes sense, however, when I then try to import my LexisChooser into my Lexis model to use the LexisChooser as a widget, I get the error below.

ImportError: cannot import name 'Lexis' from 'lexis.models'

I realize this is due to a circular import error issue because I have subclasses that are importing the Lexis Class in order to build the LexisChooser widget and then I am trying to import that widget into the Lexis Class.

I know this isn't a bug with Wagtail nor is it a problem with wagtail-generic-chooser, However, does anyone have any idea how I can refactor the code to make this function so that I can use a LexisChooser on a field of the Lexis Model.

Below is my code.

## views.py create a view

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from generic_chooser.views import ModelChooserViewSet
from lexis.models import Lexis

class LexisChooserViewSet(ModelChooserViewSet):

    icon = 'user'
    model = Lexis
    page_title = _("Choose A Lexis Term")
    per_page = 20
    order_by = 'term'
    fields = ['term']
```

## wagtail_hooks.py register view

```
from wagtail.core import hooks
from .views import LexisChooserViewSet

@hooks.register('register_admin_viewset')
def register_lexis_chooser_viewset():
    return LexisChooserViewSet('lexis_chooser', url_prefix='lexis-chooser')
```

## widgets.py create a widget

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from generic_chooser.widgets import AdminChooser
from lexis.models import Lexis

class LexisChooser(AdminChooser):

     choose_one_text = _('Choose a Lexis')
     choose_another_text = _('Choose another Lexis')
     link_to_chosen_text = _('Edit this Lexis')
     model = Lexis
     choose_modal_url_name = 'lexis_chooser:choose'
```

## lexis/models.py use widget

```
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.core.models import Orderable
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel
from chooser_panels.widgets import LexisChooser


# Orderable link to multiple other linked lexis terms
class LexisLink(Orderable):

    page = ParentalKey("lexis.Lexis", related_name="lexis_link")

    term_link = models.ForeignKey(
        'lexis.Lexis', 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        related_name='term_linked', 
        null=True
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("term_link", widget=LexisChooser)
    ]


class Lexis(ClusterableModel):

    template = "lexis/lexis_page.html"
    term = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    panels = [
        FieldPanel("term"),
        InlinePanel('lexis_link', label='Linked Lexis Terms'), 
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.term

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Lexis"
        verbose_name_plural = "Lexis"
```

This, unfortunately, results in a circular import error: 
ImportError: cannot import name 'Lexis' from 'lexis.models'

On researching this error, I found that people recommend importing Lexis within the class as required rather than at the top of each file, but that doesn't seem to work with the subclassing as outlined above, because I get the same error.

If you have any ideas on how I can refactor the code to make it work and not create the circular import error it would be much appreciated.

I am running 
Django 3, 
python 3.7,
wagtail 2.8

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your models file into two separate files containing `Lexis` and `LexisLink`, [as demonstrated in the documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package)

Then `LexisLink` can refer to `LexisChooser` while it cleanly refers to the `Lexis` model.

Comment: Brilliant that worked! Thanks @OregonTrail! I tried to upvote your answer but because I am new to StackOverflow they don't count it until I get 15 votes or something. One question I have about your solution is does this work due to fixing namespace issues? By using the init.py does it keep the namespace clean so there is no conflict?

Comment: Hmm, not really. The reason that it works is simply that there is no circular reference, and thus no execution-order-dependent behavior.  `__init__.py` is always present and executed for every python module which is a directory. You can accept my answer by clicking the check mark : )